# Silverlight app works in aspx page, not MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I'm having trouble getting my Silverlight app to show in an MVC3 Razor View.

When I add the application and it generates the test page (TestAppTestPage.aspx in my case), I can browse to the page and the app works fine. If I copy the same code to an MVC Razor view, then browse to the controller action, nothing happens with the application:

```
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/TestApp.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
```

If I look at the developer console for Chrome, the only thing I see different is the following warning: "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined". I'm not sure if this is related.

I've looked at various guides on Silverlight and MVC, and copying relevant portions of their code produces no results either. I've played with adjusting the path, using relative urls, nothing. I've also checked IIS settings, but because it works fine in the aspx test page, I suspect that's not the cause.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but have you tried using Url.Content? e.g. <param name="source" value="<%= Url.Content("~/ClientBin/TestApp.xap") %>" /> I poached this from an MVC 2 app I have, not sure if Url.Content is still preferred in MVC 3.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks much. If you'd like to give it as an answer, I can mark it as accepted. It's weird because when playing with different paths (value="~/ClientBin/TestApp.xap", etc.) if I got the path wrong, it would return a 404 for the app. So I figured when it wasn't, the path was ok. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on mfanto's comment, turning my comment into an answer.

Was guessing in my comment, but I've had issues when NOT using Url.Content for any external files. So the fix would be to use something like

```
<param name="source" value="<%= Url.Content("~/ClientBin/TestApp.xap") %>" />
```

Note that that is from an MVC 2 app.